# Problemas ao importar cx_oracle em python 3.4 64 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle11g

Estou com um problema com o cx_oracle no python 64 bits.
Instalei esta versão do cx_oracle: cx_Oracle-5.2.1-11g.win-amd64-py3.4.
Mas ao importar no python `import cx_Oracle`, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido.
```

Achei estranho, porque o arquivo é para windows 64 bits e mesmo assim, ele reclama por não ser um aplicativo 32 bits. 
Como posso contornar este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tente instalar pelo [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) como é informado na [página do cx_Oracle no Source Forge](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/).

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

O pip sempre verifica a versão do Python na hora de baixar a biblioteca. Se o seu Python for 64 bits, o mesmo irá procurar uma versão da biblioteca para 64 bits, e se não existir, informará que não há nenhuma disponível. Geralmente é mais seguro do que instalar "manualmente". O Python é **cheio** destas discrepâncias, então recomendo muito utilizar o pip sempre que possível.

EDIT:

Como é evidenciado [nessa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/1795924), no caso do erro `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`, abra o CMD e utilize o comando com SET correspondente à versão do seu Visual Studio (Se não tiver, instale):

- Visual Studio 2010 (VS10): `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%`
- Visual Studio 2012 (VS11): `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%`
- Visual Studio 2013 (VS12): `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%`
- Visual Studio 2015 (VS14): `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%`

Comment: Fiz isso @Ericson Willians, mas deu erro.

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: @fredsilva, Editei a resposta com uma solução para este erro.

Comment: fiz o procedimento que você falou, mas o erro persiste.